# foreach loop return problem

Tags: php, loops, foreach

hi i write a function to find in array but its not working when loop find something match its not retuning true value checks to the end any idea

```
function findinArray($find,$array){
    foreach($find as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($find,$array)) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
    }       }
}
if(findinArray(array("a","b"),array("a")){
         echo "Match";
}
```

thanks

Comment: What should the function do? What is the *found* condition?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A function can only return once, so your function will always return on the first iteration. If you want it to return true on the first match, and false if no match was found, try the version below.

```
function findinArray($find, $array) {
    foreach ($find as $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $array)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (findinArray(array("a","b"), array("a")) {
    echo "Match";
}
```

(You had also made errors in how you use the values in the foreach, and you have forgotten a `}`)

Comment: that’s what i need thank you yes there was error but that was accrued while posting here i get the idea now

Comment: Your function does not use $array at all.

Answer (score 5):

It should be `in_array($value, $array)`. But you could just do `count(array_intersect())`.

Answer (score -1):

you are passing first argument an array in `in_array()` it should be the value 
change it to

```
function findinArray($find,$array){
    foreach($find as $key => $value){
        if (in_array($value,$array)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }      
}
```

Comment: It would always return false if the first iteration doesn't match